# Will every change in Ionic force the customers to update the Ionic app again and again?

Tags: ionic-framework, web-applications, system-design

If I make changes to the HTML/CSS/JS code of my ionic code, will the customer have to update the app or will it be updated dynamically?

As far as I know, we just push a website into an app and deploy it. When we change the code of your website and deploy it, the website changes show up automatically.

I wonder if Ionic runs the same way? Some people suggest that it is just running the app in a web view. So the app is intact, I change the website, what will it do?

I really want to know about this because we are trying to modernise our application. Our application depends on the server too much for view rendering and for all the logic. I want to make the client a little independent but at the same time keep the changes dynamic like they are right now.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes you have to release every update on Playstore / Appstore. But there is a plugin to autoupdate you application using Capacitor.  https://github.com/Cap-go/capacitor-updater

Comment: If properly designed using web views, you can push certain types of content updates "live"

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Okay so using the capacitor, if I make any changes to the application's web code, it will automatically get pushed to the client?
Thanks :-)

Comment: Not "Automatically" user still have to click Update inside your application, but you don't need to release every time on play/app stores. you can add a check inside your application if there is an update available you can prompt users to update application.